# How to find out the registered name of a library in C++ compilation

Tags: c++, compilation, shared-libraries

When I do the link phase in C++ compilation to produce an executable, I often need to use the -l flag to link a few libraries. For example,

```
-lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_videoio -lsigc-2.0 -lglibmm-2.4 -lglib-2.0  -lstdc++ -lncurses -lflycapture
```

My question is how do I know the names of these libraries in the first place? 
For example, if I want to use the `opencv/highgui.h` library, how do I know the  name is `opencv_highgui` instead of `opencv-highgui`? Are there any commands I can use to figure out what libraries have been registered to the **Linux** system? Thanks!

Comment: The aren't registered in any way. They just are in the directories defined by your library path. You can just list the files in those places. And you know the names because you use the libraries and documentation says which ones you're using.

Comment: Are you asking how to find out which libraries have to be linked?

Comment: Edited the question. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: *"How to find out the registered name of a library in C++ compilation"* and *"Are there any commands I can use to figure out what libraries have been registered to the Linux system?"* seem to be two completely different questions.

Answer (score 0):

If a function you try to use is not in any "standard" library, you will get a linker error reporting the missing function name. Read the manual page for the function (e.g., `man crypt` for the function `crypt`). The name of the library will be usually mentioned in the page:

> Link with -lcrypt.